# AMPscript issue with IF AND

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Here is my script:

```
%%[IF[Language] == "FR"  AND [Gender] == "F" THEN]%%
    Chère 
%%[ELSE]%%
    Cher 
%%[ELSEIF[Language] == "NL"  THEN]%%
    Beste 
%%[ELSE]%%
    Beste 
%%[ENDIF]%% 

%%FirstName%% %%LastName%%,
%%=UpperCase([Language])=%%, 
%%=LowerCase([Gender])=%%
%%=UpperCase([EmailAddress])=%%
```

In Belgium we're bilingual French and Dutch and need to display the salutations accordingly.

Comment: Hi @user45515, welcome to SFSE! for future reference, avoid including salutations and any mentions of being a beginner. A clear description of the Issue in the post would also be appreciated, not only mentioning that there is an issue. Take some time to view [ask] and take the [tour]. Thank!

Comment: Thank you for the kind welcome to a beginner. I'll indeed take the tour to see how to ask questions to the community. Best rgds Jean-Luc

Comment: Also, make sure you accept an answer if it helped resolve the issue you are facing, looking forward for more questions and participation on SFSE on you part, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it seems like you are only checking for French gender, and the same salutation is used for Dutch. In that case you could try this:

```
    %%[

        IF([Language] == "FR"  AND [Gender] == "F") THEN]%%Chère 


%%[ELSEIF ([Language] == "FR" AND [Gender] != "F") THEN]%%Cher 
    %%[ELSEIF ([Language] == "NL"  [Gender] == "F") THEN]%%Beste
    %%[ENDIF]%% 
    %%FirstName%% %%LastName%%,
    %%=UpperCase([Language])=%%, 
    %%=LowerCase([Gender])=%%
    %%=UpperCase([EmailAddress])=%%
```

OR

```
    %%[IF([Language] == "FR"  AND [Gender] == "F") THEN]%%Chère 
    %%[ELSEIF ([Language] == "FR" AND [Gender] != "F") THEN]%%Cher 
    %%[ELSE]%%Beste
    %%[ENDIF]%% 
    %%FirstName%% %%LastName%%,
    %%=UpperCase([Language])=%%, 
    %%=LowerCase([Gender])=%%
    %%=UpperCase([EmailAddress])=%%
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers clarifying the use of ELSEIF. I prefer your second one. Best regards Jean-Luc

Comment: Sorry Data_Kid but I'm in trouble as the following script doesn't work properly: %%[IF[Language] == "FR"  AND [Gender] == "F" THEN]%%Chère %%[ELSEIF [Language] == "FR" AND [Gender] == "M" THEN]%%Cher %%[ELSEIF[Language]=="NL" THEN]%%Beste %%[ENDIF]%% %%FirstName%% %%LastName%%,
%%=ProperCase([Language])=%%,
%%=UpperCase([Gender])=%%
%%=LowerCase([EmailAddress])=%%

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Indeed the FR/F get Cher and not Chère!?! Thanks already for your help. Rgds Jean-Luc

Comment: does it work for beste?

Comment: Yes but it seems the first IF is not working properly...

Comment: Ive added parentheses (brackets) to it. Try this

Comment: Perfect if it's working accept and upvote

Answer (score 0):

@Data_Kid's answer is correct. I don't speak Dutch, but there's potentially a nuance with French with whether you know the gender, but do not know the customer's first name. This may not be useful if your FirstName field is always populated...

```
<!--
%%[
    VAR @salutation, @firstname

    IF EMPTY(Language) THEN
        SET @salutation = 'Beste'
    ELSEIF Language == 'FR' AND Gender == "F" THEN
        SET @salutation = 'Chère'
    ELSEIF Language == 'FR' THEN
        SET @salutation = 'Cher'
    ELSE
        SET @salutation = 'Beste'
    ENDIF

    IF EMPTY(FirstName) THEN
        IF Language == "FR" AND Gender == "F" THEN
            SET @firstname = 'Cliente'
        ELSEIF @language == 'FR' THEN
            SET @firstname = 'Client'
        ELSE
            SET @firstname = 'Klant'
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        SET @firstname = FirstName
    ENDIF
]%%
-->
%%=v(@salutation)=%% %%=v(@firstname)=%%,
```